# Induction Motor Problem

Tags: capacitor, motor, wiring, induction-motor

I have an induction motor running hot and slow in the direction it's supposed to but when I change the lead wires so it runs in the opposite direction it runs as it should. Is there any reason as to why? Could it be a problem with the capacitor? It's a single-phase 200V.

Comment: The capacitor could be faulty or too large invalue .smaller cap makes less torque and bigger cap increases idle current and therefore heat .Also is the motor 50 or 60 Hz  are you on 50 or 60 HZ AND is your mains more than 200 V ? .

Comment: Sorry about that I should have elaborated, it's 60 Hz 220 VAC and it's using the capacitor that it is rated to run with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the motor runs properly in one direction, you should check to make sure you are using the proper connections for forward operation. You should also consider what the load is when the motor is running in each direction. A load such as a fan or centrifugal pump may require less torque when running in reverse. If the motor is running properly when it is lightly loaded, but hot and slow when it is normally loaded, the capacitor or the starting winding may be defective.

Answer (score 0):

The single-phase motor does not deliver the rated torque if the connections of starting and main winding circuits are not proper. The improper connections of the capacitor and winding cause the phase difference between the current of starting and the main winding less than 90 degrees, and the motor does not deliver the rated torque.

From your question, it is not evident whether the motor is the capacitor start or the capacitor start & capacitor-run motor. You may check the healthiness of the capacitor and the proper connections of the motor winding and capacitor.